# Use an expression to subset R6Class based on attributes

Tags: r, expression, subset, r6

I have a R6 class `BarContainer` that contains a vector of `Bar`, where `Bar` is another R6 class. I would like to implemented a method `subset` in `BarContainer` that would subset the vector of `Bar` to match with the expression given as argument.

```
Bar = R6::R6Class(
    ### Class name
    "Bar",

    ### Public members
    public = list(
        ### Attributes
        a = -1,
        b = -1,
        c = -1,

        ### Initialize
        initialize = function(A, B, C)
        {
            self$a = A
            self$b = B
            self$c = C
        }
    )
)

BarContainer = R6::R6Class(
    ### Class name
    "BarContainer",

    ### Public members
    public = list(
        ### Attributes
        self$bars = c(),

        ### Initialize
        initialize = function(input)
        {
            bars = input
        }#,

        ### Subset
        subset = function(expr)
        {
            # ??? self[eval(parse(text=expr))] ???
        }
    )
)
```

Here is a possible use case for `subset`

```
mySubsettedContainer = myContainer$subset(a == 3 && (b > 0 || c > 0) )
```

How could this be implemented? Any other solution (eventually using several expressions or something else) to implement this `subset` method?

Note that `Bar` has a whole bunch of helpful methods and this oop approach really clean things up. I would like to avoid keep my `Bar` objects as rows of a `data.frame` (e.g. `bars = data.frame(a = .., b = .., c = ..)`) even if it would make the implementation of a `subset` method in `BarContainer` much easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want `BarContainer$subset` to work in this way, you will need to capture the expression and evaluate it for each `Bar` in `BarContainer` to get a logical vector, then use this to subset the `bars` field in your container. The resulting list of `Bar` objects can then be passed to a `BarContainer$new` call to return a new `BarContainer` with the subsetted `Bar` objects.

You can capture the expression with `match.call()` and evaluate it in the context of each `Bar` using an `lapply`, though you need to represent each `Bar` as a list within the `lapply` for it to be a valid evaluation context. That means the implementation would look something like this:

```r
BarContainer = R6::R6Class(
  ### Class name
  "BarContainer",
  
  ### Public members
  public = list(
    ### Attributes
    bars = c(),
    
    ### Initialize
    initialize = function(input)
    {
      self$bars = input
    },
    
    ### Subset
    subset = function(expr)
    {
      ex <- as.list(match.call()[-1])$exp
      ss <- sapply(self$bars, function(x){
        eval(ex, envir = as.list(x), enclos = parent.frame())})
      return(BarContainer$new(self$bars[ss]))
    }
  )
)
```

So we can create an example set-up like this:

```
# Create 4 Bars for our container:
bar1 <- Bar$new(1, 1, 1)
bar2 <- Bar$new(2, 2, 2)
bar3 <- Bar$new(3, 3, 3)
bar4 <- Bar$new(4, 4, 4)

# Populate our container:
bar_container <- BarContainer$new(c(bar1, bar2, bar3, bar4))
```

And our subset function works as expected:

```
subsetted_container <- bar_container$subset(a > 1 & c < 4)

subsetted_container$bars
#> [[1]]
#> <Bar>
#>   Public:
#>     a: 2
#>     b: 2
#>     c: 2
#>     clone: function (deep = FALSE) 
#>     initialize: function (A, B, C) 
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> <Bar>
#>   Public:
#>     a: 3
#>     b: 3
#>     c: 3
#>     clone: function (deep = FALSE) 
#>     initialize: function (A, B, C)
```

Remember, the subsetted `BarContainer` won't hold *copies* of the original `Bar` objects, but pointers to the objects themselves. So if you alter the first `Bar` within the subsetted container, it will alter `bar2` and the second `Bar` in the non-subsetted container. I'm guessing this is the desired behaviour anyway, but if not you will have to deep clone each `Bar` as part of your subsetting method.